# Java Text Adventure: Displaying the Game

Tags: java

How would I go about displaying my text adventure game when played? Do I have to run the program from the command line, or is there another way which would look better? I am still very new to programming.

Comment: "displaying my text adventure game when played" what do you mean? Is it ```System.out.println```?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways.  Quite a few in fact.  But whether they "look better", and are generaly worth the effort will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: No, I understand how to do that. What I mean is, as far as I can tell, I have to run the program by executing it in the command prompt. Is there anything that I can use instead of the command prompt? Just a window where all of my coding goes basically? For example, you execute lets say, a 2d rpg game with canvas or jframe or something like that(as I said, I am still very new). Is there a different window besides command prompt that I can play my game from? Can I make my own window?

Comment: Thank you Stephen. My reasoning is that I want people to actually play the game without me starting it up for them from the command prompt. I want a clean looking window without all of the extra stuff that you read in the command prompt, if that makes any sense.

Comment: *"My reasoning is that I want people to actually play the game without me starting it up for them from the command prompt."* - Sounds like a good reason to teach >>them<< to do it :-)

Comment: True..But at the same time, not everybody is interested in learning things like that, and I respect that. Looks like command prompt is the easiest way for now, so I guess I will stick to it..Now if I wanted to share my finished project online for other people to try out my game, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: If the issue is just "running the program", create a Windows Shortcut (or as appropriate launcher) for your OS. It will still be the same text game, but the the user can "click an icon" to launch it.

Comment: Good idea. I'll have to figure out how to do that. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you "could" also construct and display a java.awt.Window and either draw text directly to the screen, or place a TextArea in the Window, and keep appending text to it (and removing lines off the top to keep from overflowing the text buffer).

additionally, you could create a Swing Window and either draw directly to the window or add a JTextArea to it, and likewise, append and trim lines as the game progresses.